# Move UI element with keyboard nativescript (IOS)

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

On my nativescript app - I have a button at the bottom of a screen. On the screen there is a Text area. When the user taps in the Text Area, a virtual keyboard appears. At this point, I want the button at the bottom to move up and appear just on top of the virtual keyboard. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this in both android and iOS?

Code

```
<GridLayout>
<ActionBar title="" backgroundColor="#f82462" top="0" left="0">
    <NavigationButton (tap)="goBack()"></NavigationButton>
</ActionBar>
<GridLayout rows="*, auto">
    <GridLayout row ='0' rows="auto *" columns="">
        <GridLayout row="0" rows="" columns="">
            <Button text="Top Button" (tap)="goNext()"></Button>                
        </GridLayout>
        <GridLayout row="1" backgroundColor="#f82462">
            <TextView [(ngModel)]="xyz" class="input" hint="Write your question as a complete sentence.Click on camera to add images if required." returnkeyType="done" id="questionText"></TextView>
        </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
<StackLayout row='1'>
    <Button text="Next" (tap)="goNext()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: I usually add a button to the right of the navbar in this kind of situations. Btw, did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager?

Comment: Thanks for the response @EddyVerbruggen. In my UI I have a search bar within the Action bar and cant place anything else there. For IOS I have the iqkeyboard installed but unfortunately it does not help me achieve my goal of moving the button to the top of the keyboard when it appears.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to test this right now, but have you tried to wrap everything inside the main GridLayout in `<ScrollView> ... </ScrollView>`

Comment: this worked for me . At least in Android. Never tested on iOS

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem for my instant chat application, here is the solution : https://gist.github.com/elvticc/0c789d08d57b1f4d9273f7d93a7083ec

```
// Also use IQKeyboardManager to customize the iOS keyboard
// See https://github.com/tjvantoll/nativescript-IQKeyboardManager

// let iqKeyboard: IQKeyboardManager = IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager();
// iqKeyboard.toolbarDoneBarButtonItemText             = "OK";
// iqKeyboard.canAdjustAdditionalSafeAreaInsets        = true;
// iqKeyboard.shouldFixInteractivePopGestureRecognizer = true;

// Angular
[...]
import { OnInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
[...]

// NativeScript
[...]
import { ios as iosApp } from "tns-core-modules/application/application";
[...]

@ViewChild("element") private _element: ElementRef<StackLayout>; // FlexboxLayout, GridLayout, etc.

private _keyboardHeight: number = 0;
private _elementHeight:  number = 0;
private _observerIDs:    Array<object> = new Array();

// Start events when the component is ready
ngOnInit(): void {

    // iOS keyboard events
    if (iosApp) {

        let eventNames: Array<string> = [
                UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
                UIKeyboardDidShowNotification,
                UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
            ];

        // Catch the keyboard height before it appears
        this._observerIDs.push({
            event: eventNames[0],
            id: iosApp.addNotificationObserver(eventNames[0], (event) => {

                    let currHeight: number = this._keyboardHeight,
                        newHeight:  number = event.userInfo.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey).CGRectValue.size.height;

                    if (currHeight != newHeight) {

                        this._keyboardHeight = newHeight;

                    }

                })
        });

        // Position the element according to the height of the keyboard
        this._observerIDs.push({
            event: eventNames[1],
            id: iosApp.addNotificationObserver(eventNames[1], (event) => {

                    if (this._elementHeight == 0) {

                        this._elementHeight = this._element.nativeElement.getActualSize().height;

                    }

                    this._element.nativeElement.height = this._keyboardHeight + this._elementHeight;

                })
        });

        // Reposition the element according to its starting height
        this._observerIDs.push({
            event: eventNames[2],
            id: iosApp.addNotificationObserver(eventNames[2], () => {

                    this._element.nativeElement.height = this._elementHeight; // or "auto";

                })
        });

    }

}

// Stop events to avoid a memory leak
ngOnDestroy(): void {

    if (iosApp) {

        let index: number = 0;

        for (index; index < this._observerIDs.length; index++) {

            let observerId: number = this._observerIDs[index]['id'],
                eventName:  string = this._observerIDs[index]['event'];

            iosApp.removeNotificationObserver(observerId, eventName);

        }

    }

}
```

Marcel Ploch's original : https://gist.github.com/marcel-ploch/bf914dd62355049a0e5efb4885ca4c6e